# C++ '<class name> has not been declared' and '<class name> has no field <field name>' errors

Tags: c++

I'm doing an assignment for class and I'm getting weird compile errors.

The errors are saying `error: 'Noble' has not been declared` and `error: class 'Warrior' does not have any field named 'pBoss'`.

I'm new to C++ so I really don't get what I'm doing wrong here - it seems like I declared both classes and all the member fields.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
using namespace std;

class Warrior {
public:
    Warrior(string name, double str) : name(name), strength(str), pBoss(nullptr) {}
    bool hire(Noble* noble) { }
    bool fire(Noble* noble) { }
    void lost() { }
    void won(double damageRatio) { }
    string getName() const { return name; }
    double getStrength() const { return strength; }
    Noble* getBoss() const { return pBoss; }
    void display(ostream& os = cout) const { }
private:
    string name;
    double strength;
    Noble* pBoss;
};

class Noble {
public:
    Noble(string name) : name(name), alive(true) {}
    bool hire(Warrior& war) { }
    bool fire(Warrior& war) { }
    bool battle(Noble& enemy) { }
    void display(ostream& os = cout) const { }
private:
    vector<Warrior*> army;
    string name;
    double strength;
    bool alive; 
    void lost() { } 
    void won(double damage) { }
};
```

I took out the function descriptions so this won't be too long, but let me know if there is anything I didn't include and I'll update the post!

Comment: Look up forward declarations. (hint: `bool hire(Noble* noble) { }` The compiler has no clue what `Noble` is at this point)

Comment: It doesn't, because its called `pBoss;`.

Comment: Oh crap, that's my bad in writing the post... It's all pBoss in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time you define `Warrior`, `Noble` is not yet defined. C++ works line by line. To fix this you could forward declare the classes.

```
// forward declaration
class Warrior;
class Noble;

class Warrior {
  // ...
};

class Noble {
   // ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`Warrior` has no idea what a `Noble` is. You need to forward declare `Noble`. Place this before the `Warrior` declaration:

```
class Noble;

class Warrior { ...
```

Furthermore, you've misspelled `pBoss` in the `Warrior` constructor, change the constructor to:

```
Warrior(string name, double str) : name(name), strength(str), pBoss(nullptr) {}
```

Lastly you have an extra close brace floating around in `Noble` after the `display` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have an extra brace in your noble class:

```
class Noble {
public:
    Noble(string name) : name(name), alive(true) {}
    bool hire(Warrior& war) { }
    bool fire(Warrior& war) { }
    bool battle(Noble& enemy) { }
    void display(ostream& os = cout) const { }
    } // <-- out of place?
private:
    vector<Warrior*> army;
    string name;
    double strength;
    bool alive; 
    void lost() { } 
    void won(double damage) { }
};
```